# Angular CLI build target vs environment

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In the [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), what is the difference between the `--target` and `--environment` options when running the [build](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) command?

From the documentation:

> ng build can specify both a build target (--target=production or --target=development) and an environment file to be used with that build (--environment=dev or --environment=prod). By default, the development build target and environment are used.

However, they never really clarify the distinction between the two.

From what I can gather, the `--environment` flag controls which environment file (`environment.ts` vs `environment.prod.ts`) gets used when doing the build. But then what does `--target` control?

Comment: Did you read the section of that page on `--dev` vs. `--prod` builds? It explains exactly that with a table comparing their settings, plus a list of the non-flaggable production settings.

Comment: Here is the link to the aforementioned table - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--dev-vs---prod-builds

Comment: Based on that table, is my understanding correct that the `target` flag does not *directly* affect anything about the build process, and is rather just a shortcut for setting other flags which do? Further, while you can define additional *environments*, you cannot define additional *targets* (there's only the built-in ones `dev` and `prod`)?

Comment: @SergeyK I was wondering the same exact thing. It seems you are right about this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**`--environment`** is a key for the *apps[0].environments* object from *.angular-cli.json*

It is like a profile for the running environment (for example: local, development server, test server, CI server, stage server, production server and so on). The value of the *apps[0].environments* object is a file name with all settings for the environment. There you could set up backend endpoint, keys and whatever else you want. Then you could use it inside your code:

```
import {environment} from '@environments/environment';
const userEndPoint = `${environment.apiRoot}/user/`;
```

Every environment could be *production* (environment.production === true) or non production i.e. *development* (environment.production === false). This is a *target* which could be defined also with the next parameter:

**`--target`** is a enum of two values: `development` or `production`. It is a 'meta' flags, that set other flags:

> Flag                | `--dev` | `--prod`
>   ---                 | ---     | ---
>   `--aot`             | `false` | `true`
>   `--environment`     | `dev`   | `prod`
>   `--output-hashing`  | `media` | `all`
>   `--sourcemaps`      | `true`  | `false`
>   `--extract-css`     | `false` | `true`
>   `--named-chunks`    | `true`  | `false`
>   `--build-optimizer` | `false` | `true` with AOT and Angular 5
>
> --prod also sets the following non-flaggable settings:
>   - Adds service worker if configured in .angular-cli.json.
>   - Replaces process.env.NODE_ENV in modules with the production value (this is needed for some libraries, like react).
>   - Runs UglifyJS on the code.

from https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build/1cf783837c392f5fadc7286e1fb28220b9a1b507#--dev-vs---prod-builds

Answer (score 1):

As of Angular CLI 6, the environment option has been [deprecated](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v6.0.0).

> The environment option in build related commands is replaced with fileReplacements, please see the wiki for how it can be used.

The build system has been overhauled to be more easily configurable. [Build configuration](https://angular.io/cli/build#description) options have been moved to the workspace configuration file (angular.json).

> A "production" configuration is created by default when you use the CLI to create the project, and you can use that configuration by specifying the --prod option.

The difference between the default development configuration and production is that the development configuration uses the CLI defaults (e.g. source maps) while the production configuration enables AOT, optimizations, etc. The `--prod` meta-flag targets the "production" configuration and enables the [runtime production mode](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#enable-runtime-production-mode).

> Switching to production mode makes it run faster by disabling development specific checks such as the dual change detection cycles.

The term "environment" has even been [replaced](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/12837/files#r230467790) with "build target" in parts of the documentation. The `--target` option was replaced with `--configuration` as early as [CLI version 6](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v6.0.0/docs/documentation/build.md) as well.

Comment: what about the --target?

it also not executable anymore when adding this flag in ng build command

Comment: The --target option has been deprecated from at least version 6 and was replaced with --configuration.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation: [Build Targets and Environment Files](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#build-targets-and-environment-files)

> `ng build` can specify both a build target (`--target=production` or
>   `--target=development`) and an environment file to be used with that build (`--environment=dev` or `--environment=prod`). By default, the
>   development build target and environment are used.

**Build target set to Production has following effects:**

1. Ahead of time compilation, which means Angular compiler doesn't get included in the final build, which implies faster render, small size
2. Hashing of bundle files
3. Minification of generated javascript files
4. Angular runs in production mode, hence it stops checking every change detection twice
5. Progressive Web Apps only work in this mode

Comment: can you explain what this script means:  "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false",

Answer (score 0):

--target=production means that angular-cli will use everything for build, that it uses for production. --environment=prod means that the object, that you have in app "environment" will have "production" flag=true.