# Does Angular define a directory structure for organizing assets by environment?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v7

Angular defines [app and assets directories](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#default-app-project-files) that seem to contain source and assets for all environments (development, production, etc.). The environments directory is for configuration, and [is being replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160876/angular-cli-build-target-vs-environment/55144631#55144631) by configurations. If there are assets or a large amount of source that apply to a specific environment, does Angular define how to organize those files? I could not find so in the documentation, so I am currently considering organizing those files under environment specific directories.

```
src/app
src/assets
src/development/assets
src/production/assets
```

These files are more than configuration. Similar to comments made in this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4150), there will be assets like images for each environment.

Comment: You would do something like multiple app configuration. See doc stories: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps. Then you would just change the assets to point to w/e location. Alternatively you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46859191/6736888

Comment: I am using CLI 7, so I would use multiple build configurations. Its similar, so I guess your answer is no. Its up to the developer to determine the directory structure. I hoping for a more opinionated recommendation from the framework as this will spread across projects.

Comment: Not sure if I understand? The link you just recently added also points to multiple apps which is posted by 1 of the angular-cli maintainer. Also `opinionated recommendation` is off-topic.

Comment: I updated the question to be more on topic. I am aware of defining multiple configurations. I am asking if Angular defines the directory structure for the assets themselves.

Comment: Assets in an Angular application get delivered to the client, along with the transpiled JavaScript. What sort of assets do you have that would differ between application environments? Or, is the application meant to allow the user to manage environments? Either way, the structure is up to you. Do whatever is best for your application. Angular doesn’t, and shouldn’t, care. Just make sure you add any directories outside of the assets directory to the *assets* array in the *angular.json* file so they get delivered to the client as needed.

Comment: @R.Richards Thank you, I understand. I have images that are different per environment, and I have configuration files, fonts, and non-assets (third-party scripts) that only exist in one environment, because the application can exist in multiple environments (on-premise, cloud, suite, etc.).